# CASE WHEN Not displaying accurately

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to display a True or false value for [W-9 Uploaded],[E&O Uploaded],[License Uploaded]. But it always results in 'No'. I can never get a 'YES'

```
select distinct tp.License_Exp_Date AS [License Expiration Date],
tp.EO_Exp_Date AS [E&O Expiration Date],
tp.Insurance_Exp_Date AS [Insurance Expiration Date],
tp.Brokerage_Company_Name AS [Agent Company],
pd.agent_id AS [Agent ID],
tp.Other_Phone AS [Agent Phone],
tu.First_Name + ' ' + tu.Last_Name AS [Agent Name],
[W-9 Uploaded] = CASE WHEN tr.User_Id = ta.User_ID and ta.Type_ID = 5 and  ta.Sub_Type_ID = 4 and ta.IsDeleted = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
[E&O Uploaded] = CASE WHEN tr.User_Id = ta.User_ID and ta.Type_ID = 5 and  ta.Sub_Type_ID = 2 and ta.IsDeleted = 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
[License Uploaded] = CASE WHEN tp.Real_Estate_Sales_License IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(Real_Estate_Sales_License)) <> '' AND NameOnLicense IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(NameOnLicense)) <> ''  AND License_Exp_Date IS NOT NULL AND GETDATE() < License_Exp_Date THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
tu.Email AS [Agent Email]
from amp.dbo.tbl_profile tp (nolock)
left join amp.dbo.tbl_user tu (nolock)
    on tp.Resnet_Agent_ID = tu.Resnet_Agent_ID
left join amp.dbo.tbl_Resume tr (nolock)
    on tp.Resnet_Agent_ID= tr.Resnet_Agent_ID
left  join amp.dbo.tbl_Attachment ta (nolock)
on tr.Resume_Id = ta.Business_ID
left join resnet_mysql.dbo.property_details pd
on pd.agent_id = tp.Resnet_Agent_ID
order by [License Expiration Date],[E&O Expiration Date] desc;
```

[image]

```
select * from amp.dbo.tbl_Attachment

where Type_ID = 5 and Sub_Type_ID =4 and IsDeleted = 0
```

[image]

Comment: Does tr.user_id = ta.user_id for those examples?

Comment: yes it does, but it returns duplicate values when i join under that ID

Comment: If the conditions of the case statement are true, I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't get a "yes" where you should get a "yes", so I would suggest you run the same query (the first one up above) but only selecting the relevant columns (tr.user_id, ta.user_id, ta.type_id, etc) and just visually look at why it might not be producing the results you expect it should. There's not really a way to help you without seeing the data.

Comment: Add each of the columns involved to your `select` (`tr.User_ID`, `ta.User_ID`, ... ) and use a `where` clause to narrow down some sample data. It should be pretty clear when you can see all of the values. Keep in mind that you need to expect `NULL` values when you use `outer` joins and that `is NULL` and `coalesce` are your friends.

Comment: Just noticed `... on tr.Resume_Id = ta.Business_ID ...`. Seems peculiar.

Comment: Please output tr.Resume_Id AND tr.user_id with the first query.

Comment: can you please attached  amp.dbo.tbl_Resume  table. thanks